# Passing from "relative" to "absolute" positioning while staying at the same place

Tags: jquery, css-position, draggable, resizable

I have several divs which are draggable and resizable.
The fact that the position value change from relative (draggable) to absolute (resizable) when resizing is already known but I still haven't found a solution to my problem.

What I'd like to do is convert my divs position from relative to absolute when the drag event start.

I've tried this:

```
$( ".drag" ).draggable({ containment: "window", stack: ".drag", start: function() {$(this).css({position: "absolute", top: $(this).offset().top, left: $(this).offset().left});}});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tancrede/EeU2u/

But it doesn't work.
The div keep retrieving the `top: 0px, left: 0px` position when passing to absolute.

Comment: What are you trying to set the offsets to?  It looks like when it goes to 0, 0 (draggable start) you are then setting them to 0, 0;  That is, you are setting them to their own value after it has moved to 0, 0.  Are you hoping to save the before drag value and then after draggable start set it to that value?

Comment: Maybe change the `position` to `absolute` in CSS and change the values there.

Comment: @ Seano666: Yes! Exactly!

Comment: @ Seano666: Do you know how I could do that? My jQuery skills are pretty basic...